# How do I use a for loop when reading from a dictionary that might contain a list of dicts, but might not?

Tags: python, json

I apologize in advance that the title is so confusing. It makes a lot more sense in code, so here goes:

I am parsing data from a REST API that returns JSON, and I have a bit of an issue with this particular structure:

```
{ 'Order' : [
  { 'orderID': '1',
    'OrderLines': {
      'OrderLine': [
        { 'lineID':'00001', 'quantity':'1', 'cost':'10', 'description':'foo' },
        { 'lineID':'00002', 'quantity':'2', 'cost':'23.42', 'description':'bar' }
      ]}
  }
  { 'orderID': '2',
    'OrderLines': {
      'OrderLine':
        { 'lineID':'00003', 'quantity':'6', 'cost':'12.99', 'description':'lonely' }
    }
  }
]}
```

If you'll notice, the second order only has one `OrderLine`, so instead of returning a list containing dictionaries, it returns the dictionary. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
orders_json = json.loads(from_server)
for order in orders_json['Order']:
    print 'Order ID: {}'.format(order['orderID'])
    for line in order['OrderLines']['OrderLine']:
        print '-> Line ID: {}, Quantity: {}'.format(line['lineID'], line['quantity'])
```

It works just fine for the first order, but the second order throws `TypeError: string indices must be integers` since `line` is now a string containing the dictionary, instead of a dictionary from the list. I've been banging my head against this for hours now, and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Here are some of the things I have tried:

- Using `len(line)` to see if it gave me something unique for the one line orders. It does not. It returns the number of key:value pairs in the dictionary, which in my real program is 10, which an order containing 10 lines would also return.
- Using a try/except. Well, that stops the TypeError from halting the whole thing, but I can't figure out how to address the dictionary once I've done that. Line is a string for single line orders instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check if the type is correct and then convert it to a list if necessary to have a uniform access:

```
lines = order['OrderLines']['OrderLine']
lines = [lines] if not isinstance(lines, list) else lines

for line in lines:
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Whoever designed that API did not do a terribly good job. Anyway, you could check whether `OrderLine` is a list and, if it's not, wrap it in a one-element list before doing any processing:

```
if not isinstance(order_line, list):
   order_line = [order_line]
```

That would work, my personal preference would be to get the API fixed.

Comment: I chose Constantinius' answer even though you both suggested the same fix because it put the fix on one line. I appreciate your answer, and I wish I had more influence on how the API was returning the data. I'll bug the developers of the API to see if they can return more consistent data structures!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of the object you try to access:

```
# ...
print 'Order ID: {0}'.format(order['orderID'])
lines = order['OrderLines']['OrderLine']
if isinstance(lines, list):
    for line in lines:
        print line['lineID']
elif isinstance(lines, dict):
    print lines['lineID']
else:
    raise ValueError('Illegal JSON object')
```

***Edit:** Wrapping the `dict` in a `list` as proposed by @NPE is the nicer and smarter solution.*